# Firefox and edge compability issue (Transform RotateX). Chrome is working fine. (JS, CSS and HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to recreate the 3D hover-effect likely the Steam cards but i'm having an issue with FF and Edge regarding compatibility. I use the prefixes correctly I think but it doesn't work. Chrome is working fine btw. I have the code running on Sololearn too (https://code.sololearn.com/WaQaFKu9D2er/#html)

Here's the code:

```js
function MoveAround(event) {

var cX = event.clientX;
var cY = event.clientY;

var oL = event.target.offsetLeft;
var oT = event.target.offsetTop;

var oW = event.target.offsetWidth;
var oH = event.target.offsetHeight;

var x = (cX - oL - (oW / 2)) / 5;
var y = ((cY - oT - (oH / 2)) / 5) * -1;

// Added following lines to convert negative values before representation.

while (x < 0) {
    x = x + 360;
}

while (x > 360) {
    x = x - 360;
}

while (y < 0) {
    y = y + 360;
}

while (y > 360) {
    y = y - 360;
}

var elem = event.target.style;

elem.width = "300px";
elem.height = "300px";

elem.transform = "rotateX(" + y + "deg) rotateY(" + x + "deg)";

console.log("cX: ", cX, " cY: ", cY, " oL: ", oL, " oT: ", oT, " oW: ", oW, " oH: ", oH, " x: ", x, " y: ", y)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #382525;
  
  transform: perspective(800px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#Demo {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 7px solid white;
  background-image: url("https://www.chi.lu/cats/cat.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>On Mouse Move</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mousemove.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Demo" onmousemove="MoveAround(event)">
    </div>

<script src="mousemove.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone has an idea what i'm doing wrong, please help me in this matter.

Thank you and best regards,
Claude

Comment: There's no standard `transform` style set in `moveAround` function. FF and Edge use the standard style name without the vendor prefix.

Comment: OMG, you are absolutely right. I added a line with `elem.transform = "rotateX(" + y + "deg) rotateY(" + x + "deg)";` and it's working but not as intended. It's a bit like a slowmotion reaction to the mouse move.

Comment: Seems to work fine on the stacksnippet with FF71.

Comment: @Teemu Hm, I have FF71 64bit but the snippet is not working at all. Why is it working for you? If we have a working code on your side and we are using the same browser, why isn't it working for me? Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's not the browser, it's maybe your GPU. I've ticked "Use recommended performance options" in FF's options.

Comment: That option is ticked by default, i have it too. (The GPU is a GTX2080)

Comment: @Teemu I cleared FF's cache, checked every option. Everything is in default mode. Can you confirm that the snippet behaves exactly the same in Chrome and FF please?

Comment: Somehow the effective hover area is a bit smaller in FF and Edge than in Chrome, but when the effect takes place, it is equally smooth in all of those three browsers. But there seems to be a big difference in FF and Edge, when showing the snippet in the full page mode. FF does nothing, and Egde flashes constantly between the original image and the effect, where as Chrome seems to work fine also in the full page mode.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i'm talking about. I always tried in full page mode so I didn't notice that it's working a little bit in the smaller windows. So I guess it's the calculation that causes the problem because it's based on `clientX`and so on.

1. Using `clientX` respectively `pageX` has no impact.
2. `offsetLeft`and `offsetWidth`should both be fully supported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)
3. `style`should also not be the troublemaker (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

So mybe it's time to give up :-(